# How to include PHP generated data in Dart (no Ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dart

I currently have a website using PHP (Laravel) on the server and Javascript in the client.
Now I'd like to replace the Javascript with Dart.

On the current webpage, I inject some data into the Javascript like this:

```
<script>
    var mydata = <?php echo $mydata; ?>;
    /* now do something with mydata */
</script>
```

My question is: how do I rewrite this to Dart?

My first take would be:

```
<script type="application/dart">
    main() {  
        var mydata = <?php echo $mydata; ?>
        /* now do something with mydata */
    }  
</script>
```

But this approach makes it impossible to generate Javascript code with dart2js since there is dynamically generated code included in the Dart code.

I can of course use an Ajax request, but I choose to place the generated data in the Javascript code because that makes one less HTTP request, making the webpage load faster.

So how would I go about injecting PHP generated data into Dart, without using a HTTP request while still being able to use dart2js?

Comment: Another to improve loading time is to add a prefetch tag for your json data: <link rel="subresource" href="data.json">  Then when you make the the ajax request the data will likely already have been downloaded.

Comment: That's interesting Greg, I didn't one can do that. It would still be an extra HTTP request and I want to use the data right away on load, so in my case I don't see it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to generate datas in JS like you already do and read them from Dart with [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js.html). Thus you will have to compile with *dart2js* only one time.

In your *file.php* :

```php
<script>
    var myDatasAsJsonString = "<?php echo $myDatasAsJsonString; ?>";
</script>
```

In your Dart file :

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'dart:convert' show JSON;

main() {
  final myDatasAsJsonString = js.context['myDatasAsJsonString'];
  final myDatasAsJson = JSON.decode(myDatasAsJsonString);
  /* now do something with mydata */
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks like a workable solution. I'll try that as soon as I'm back home from work. A 'pure' Dart solution might be more elegant but this will certainly work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to my own question is this:

```
<script type="application/json" id="json-data">
    <?php echo json_encode($myData); ?>
</script>
```

and import this in Dart like:

```
void main() {
    var myData = JSON.decode(querySelector('#json-data').text);
}
```